# Approximating polynomial roots without complex arithmetics

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose that we have polynomial of degree greater than two
$P(x)=a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+_\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}$
with real coefficients and we want to approximate all roots of this polynomial
without complex arithmetic 
It seems to be good idea to get quadratic factors of $P(x)$ 
$P(x)=Q(x)(x^2-px+q)+R(p,q)x+S(p,q)$ 
Now we want that after each iteration $R(p,q)$ and $S(p,q)$ be closer to zero 
until given tolerance $\varepsilon$ 
Now we need to solve system of nonliear equations
$$
R(p,q)=0\\
S(p,q)=0\\
$$
and how to solve this system and present solution in such way it is easy to write code for it

I would like to present the code I wrote

```
uses crt;
type TElem = double;
     TArray = array of TElem;
const EPS = 1e-12;

procedure Horner(deg:integer;a:TArray;z:TElem;var b:TArray;var alpha:TElem;var beta:TElem);
var k:integer;
begin
  alpha := a[deg];
  beta := 0;
  for k := deg - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    b[k]:=alpha;
    beta := alpha + z * beta;
    alpha := a[k] + z * alpha;
  end;
end;

procedure Bairstow(deg:integer;a:TArray;var b:TArray;r0,s0:TElem;var r:TElem;var s:TElem);
var i:integer;
    d,dr,ds:TElem;
    c:TArray;
begin
  SetLength(c,deg+1);
  repeat
    b[deg] := a[deg];
    b[deg-1] := a[deg-1]+r0*b[deg];
    c[deg] := 0;
    c[deg-1] := b[deg];
    for i := deg - 2 downto 0 do
    begin
      b[i] := a[i] + r0 * b[i + 1] + s0 * b[i + 2];
      c[i] := b[i + 1] + r0 * c[i + 1] + s0 * c[i + 2];
    end;
    d := (c[0] * c[2] - sqr(c[1]));
    dr := (c[1] * b[1] - c[2] * b[0])/d;
    ds := (c[1] * b[0] - c[0] * b[1])/d;
 r0 := r0 + dr;
 s0 := s0 + ds;
 until ((abs(dr)<EPS)and(abs(ds) < EPS));
 r := r0;
 s := s0;
end;

procedure PolyRoots(deg:integer;a:TArray;p0,q0:TElem;var xr:TArray;var xi:TArray);
var i:integer;
    b,c:TArray;
    p,q,d:TElem;
    stop:boolean;
begin
  SetLength(b,deg+1);
  SetLength(c,deg+1);
  for i := 0 to deg do
      c[i] := a[i]/a[deg];
  for i := 0 to deg-1 do
  begin
    xr[i] := 0;
    xi[i] := 0;
  end;
  {Modyfikacja zaproponowana przez uzytkownika Lutz}
  if odd(deg) then
  begin
    d := 0;
    for i := 0 to deg - 1 do
        if abs(c[i]) > d then
           d := abs(c[i]);
    d := d + 1;
    repeat
      Horner(deg,c,d,b,p,q);
      xr[deg-1] := d - p/q;
      stop := (abs(xr[deg-1] - d) < EPS);
      d := xr[deg-1];
    until stop;
    deg := deg - 1;
    for i := 0 to deg do
        c[i] := b[i];  
  end;
  while (deg >= 2) do
  begin
    Bairstow(deg,c,b,p0,q0,p,q);
    d := sqr(p) + 4*q;
    if (d < 0) then
    begin
      xr[deg-1] := 0.5 * p;
      xr[deg-2] := 0.5 * p;
      xi[deg-1] := -0.5 * sqrt(-d);
      xi[deg-2] := 0.5 * sqrt(-d);
    end
    else
    begin
      xr[deg-1] := 0.5 * (p - sqrt(d));
      xr[deg-2] := 0.5 * (p + sqrt(d));
    end;
    deg := deg - 2;
    for i := 0 to deg do
        c[i] := b[i+2];
    end;
    {
    if (deg = 1) then
       xr[0] := -c[0]/c[1];
    }
    end;


var
    i,deg:integer;
    a,xr,xi:TArray;
    p0,q0:TElem;
    esc : char;

begin
  ClrScr;
  WriteLn('Przyblizone rozwiazywanie rownan wielomianowych metoda Bairstowa');
  repeat
    WriteLn('Podaj stopien wielomianu');
    ReadLn(deg);
    SetLength(a,deg+1);
    SetLength(xr,deg);
    SetLength(xi,deg);
    WriteLn('Podaj poczatkowe wartosci wspolczynnikow trojmianu');
    ReadLn(p0,q0);
    WriteLn('Podaj wspolczynniki wielomianu');
    for i := deg downto 0 do
    begin
      Write('P[',i,']=');
      ReadLn(a[i]);
    end;
    PolyRoots(deg,a,p0,q0,xr,xi);
    WriteLn('Przyblizone wartosci pierwiastkow wielomianu to: ');
    for i := 0 to deg - 1 do
       if xi[i] < 0 then
          WriteLn('x[',i,']=',xr[i]:1:12,xi[i]:1:12,'*i')
       else
          WriteLn('x[',i,']=',xr[i]:1:12,'+',xi[i]:1:12,'*i');
    esc := ReadKey;
    until esc = #27;
 end.
```

I used Pascal to present the code which I have written so far
because it produces clean code which is easy to read and understand even for those who are not programmers

This code still needs to be improved because of drawbacks and pitfalls of Newton's method which is used here

Suppose we want to stay with Newton's method
Are there strategies for picking good initial guess
or maybe there is modification of Newton's method
which guaranties convergence

Comment: Do you know the [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) method?

Comment: This is the basic idea of Bairstow's method. In some sense, changing the focus to the large factor in the long polynomial division, also of the real variant of the Jenkins-Traub method.

Comment: But how to use it to systems of equations , moreover there some pitfalls when using Newton-Raphson method

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446798/apply-bairstows-method-with-the-initial-point-u-v-3-1-compute-the-correc/2449555#2449555 for an example computation of Bairstow

Comment: Please also add the input that produces the error, or incorporate this polynomial data into a test procedure.

Comment: At the moment the question does not present a problematic case. From my experience with the method, if the degree of the polynomial is odd, there is a very good chance that the quadratic factor gets computed for a (single?) real root and a root at infinity, leading to divergence in the coefficients. It is better to reduce the degree by one by finding a real root via Newton or similar, so that Bairstow is only applied to even-degree polynomials.

Comment: I tried to apply your suggestion by modifying Horner's rule (Horner's rule gives all ingrediens for Newton's method and deflation) but still in my opinion problem is in Newton's method because it is at most locally convergent

Comment: I tried also eigenvalues approach to polynomial roots There is function in Numerical recipes in C but when I tried to rewrite it to C# (C# is available for Windows users without downloading any third party software) I get uninitialized variables error moreover it is quite difficult to read that code I would like to write algorithm presented in this pdf https://pdfhost.io/v/0tQIJ0UFs_chapter4 (Algorithm 4.3 and Algorithm 4.5) but i dont know how

Answer (score 1):

The (Lin-)Bairstow method is what you ask for, the Newton method applied to the task of splitting of a quadratic factor from a polynomial

The factorization task to solve is
$$
P(x)=Q(x)·N(x),~~~~~N(x)=x^2-px+q.
$$
With an approximation for the second factor, the linearization can be written as
$$
P(x)=Q(x)·N(x)+Q(x)·ΔN(x)+ΔQ(x)·N(x)
$$
The aim is to compute the update $ΔN$. This polynomial does not change under reduction of the whole equation and all operations in it modulo $N$
$$
[P(x)\bmod N(x)] = \bigl([Q(x)\bmod N(x)]·ΔN(x)\bigr)\bmod N(x)
$$
This last system is now effectively a $2\times 2$ linear system for the coefficients $p,q$ in $ΔN(x)=-Δp·x+Δq$.

Repeat until the changes are small, or any other convergence test for Newton's method (tests for at least halving of the update length from one step to the next, tests for quadratic convergence,...)

In practical tests this iteration converges globally to some random factor for even degree polynomials. In odd-degree polynomials divergence can happen in a considerable part of the initial values, indicating a linear factor with root $x=q/p$. Either use that as a single root or split off a real root with some other method for polynomials with real coefficients, so that the next steps can proceed from even degree to even degree.

Comment: Yes but Newton's method may not converge Is there other method to solve this system of equations

Comment: That is what convergence tests are for, to determine early if the initial guess was bad to the randomly or systematically chose another. For even-degree polynomials the set of bad initial guesses is very small. This is particular to polynomials over the complex plane, for general multi-dimensional Newton method the set of good initial guesses is indeed small and becomes smaller as the dimension increases.

Comment: I wrote some code for it and Pascal gives me runtime error 207 for polynomial with repeated roots and randomly chosen initial guess

Comment: Are you using an old version of Turbo-Pascal? Can you use FreePascal instead?

Comment: I used free pascal version I even sent the code but it was deleted without reasons Jose Carlos SSantos did it

Comment: Ah yes They are complaining that i didnt edit the first post in this thread

Comment: I posted full Free Pascal code so you can test it on online compiler and wite me what improvements can be made